# How to listen for seek or playing position changes in exoplayer android kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, video-editing

I am try to implement a video editor like feature which includes adding sticker or image on top of the video preview in my app. I want to show the sticker or image on top of the view preview for my sometime. For example, If I have to show a sticker from position 2 second to 6 second, how can I do this in exoplayer?

I know we can use PlayerMessage in exoplayer to do some action at a specific position of the video but in my case, that won't work effectively I think. What's the good way to implement my requirement?

Comment: You can get current playing position of exoplayer any time you want. So you can set like if current position is between 2 to 6 then image should visible.